# PyGObject fix button size no matter what. Break label accordingly

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I'm doing an even button grid with PyGObject. Current,y I'm doing this for button sizing and addition.

```
folder_button = Gtk.Button(label=folder["label"])
folder_button.set_size_request(64,64)
folder_button.set_hexpand(False)
self.attach(folder_button,folder["column"],folder["row"],1,1)
```

Which is all fine, if the button label is small enough to fit inside the button. However, if I then have longer labels, the buttons expand to fit the label. I would like to stop this expanding, and break/scale/truncate the label accordingly. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could [ellipsize](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkLabel.html#gtk-label-set-ellipsize) it in the middle. Example:

```
label = Gtk.Label("This text is absolutely terribly too long to "
                        "fit in any decent size space on a normal window "
                        "anybody in his right mind would be using, so "
                        "please ellipsize it using a Gtk function that "
                        "calculates a decent size based on the rest of "
                        "the window by using some dots in the middle of "
                        "the text. Thank You!")
label.set_ellipsize (Pango.EllipsizeMode.MIDDLE)
folder_button = Gtk.Button(label=label)
```

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please mark it as such for other people coming here.