# Make grid of buttons fixed width & height, and wrap text

Tags: c, user-interface, button, gtk, gtk3

We have a GTK3 user interface (coded in C) in an embedded system that must stay fixed width/height in order to fit the screen.

Basically it's a fixed grid of buttons on a touchscreen, where the buttons can contain a text label or a graphical image - and the grid MUST stay fixed, all buttons the same width & height, and fitting the screen 100%.

However, on updating button text/labels with longer strings the button expands to fit which is not what we want at all.

I can't post all the code but I believe this is the relevant button creation code that would affect what we're trying to do;

```
// Number buttons 1..n
buttonId = n;
bid = buttonId - 1; // Because zero-indexing, natch
dbp = &_context->buttons[bid]; // Data about button

// Create new button, attach to global buttons
dbp->btn = gtk_button_new();

// Button name != Button CSS#ID
snprintf(value, SHORT_STR, "BTN_%02d", buttonId );
gtk_widget_set_name(dbp->btn, value);
gtk_button_set_relief(GTK_BUTTON(dbp->btn), GTK_RELIEF_NORMAL/*GTK_RELIEF_NONE*/);

// Set text label
strncpy(dbp->text, value, MAX_BUTTON_TEXT);
gtk_button_set_label (GTK_BUTTON(dbp->btn), dbp->text);

// Attempt to make labels wrap - does nothing
label  = gtk_bin_get_child(GTK_BIN(dbp->btn));
gtk_label_set_line_wrap(GTK_LABEL(label), TRUE);
//gtk_label_set_max_width_chars(GTK_LABEL(label), 0);

// Create new blank (&transprent) image
dbp->pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new(GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB, TRUE, 8, _context->innerButton.width, _conte$
gdk_pixbuf_fill(dbp->pixbuf, 0x00000000);

// Image holds pixbuf
dbp->image = (GtkImage*)gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(dbp->pixbuf);
dbp->image_modified = 0;

// Attach image to button
gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(dbp->btn), GTK_WIDGET(dbp->image));

 
// Adds an individual CSS provider per button to allow style changes
GtkStyleContext *context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(dbp->btn);
dbp->bp = gtk_css_provider_new();

// Set default colour from table of default colours
dbp->bg = get_default_colour(bid);
dbp->fg = get_label_colour(dbp->bg);

BuildButtonCSS("btnid_", buttonId, dbp->bg, dbp->fg, tstr, NULL);

// Convert CSS to provider
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(dbp->bp, tstr, -1, NULL);

// Add provider to button
gtk_style_context_add_provider (context, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(dbp->bp), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIO$

// Give the button the CSS style/class corresponding to the one we just created for it
snprintf(value, SHORT_STR, "btnid_%02d", buttonId);
gtk_style_context_add_class(context, value);

g_object_unref(dbp->bp);

// Discourage expansion (again, doesn't appear to work when label gets too long)
gtk_widget_set_hexpand(dbp->btn, FALSE);
gtk_widget_set_vexpand(dbp->btn, FALSE);

// Attach button to grid
gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(_grid), dbp->btn, c, r, 1, 1);
g_signal_connect(dbp->btn, "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK(button_press_callback), GINT_TO_P$
g_signal_connect(dbp->btn, "button_release_event", G_CALLBACK(button_release_callback), GINT_$
dbp->initialised = 1;
```

However when we update text within a button, it renders as a single (non-wrapped) line of text and causes the button to expand and totally bu&&er up the layout.

There's two problems here;

1. The text should wrap, the buttons have plenty of height but the text remains a single line
2. The buttons should be absoltuely FIXED width & height no matter what

This feels like it should be simple to do, but I'm not very familiar with GTK and all the examples out there seem to assume that you'd want everything to flex and resize itself all the time.

---

*Edit:* Tried Alexander Dmitriev's suggestion to use [ellipsize](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Label.set_ellipsize.html) - didn't seem to work although threw no errors;

```
// Experiment; ellipsize
label  = gtk_bin_get_child(GTK_BIN(dbp->btn));
gtk_label_set_ellipsize(GTK_LABEL(label),PANGO_ELLIPSIZE_END);
gtk_label_set_max_width_chars(GTK_LABEL(label), 14);
```

I also tried [this exmaple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54484081/1389218) by creating a GtkWidget label, applying the properties to it and then adding it to the button - but it seems `gtk_button_set_label` will only accept a string not a label.

Comment: [Ellipsize](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Label.set_ellipsize.html)

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev - see edit, I tried it, but it appears not to take effect (much like the set_line_wrap and label_set_max_width_chars) - I assume the underlying problem is I'm not actually extracting the label _object_ (as opposed to just the string) from the button to apply the effect to, but I can't find any examples of how to do that correctly.

Comment: [set_label](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/3.24.29/gtk/gtkbutton.c#L2158) calls [construct_child](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/3.24.29/gtk/gtkbutton.c#L1261). Try setting ellipsize every time label is updated

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev - it appears that _button_ labels are not actually _label_ widgets and hence can't have _ellipsize_ applied to them - you can put newlines in manually but button label is just a char* string not a widget.

Comment: From my recent experience trying to learn gtk3, it seems it is a crappy version and should probably be avoided if possible.  Full of bugs and missing "features".  Not that gtk4 is any better.