# GTK3 wrap text in button label

Tags: c, user-interface, button, gtk, gtk3

As a follow-on / simplification of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69300201/make-grid-of-buttons-fixed-width-height-and-wrap-text), I am trying to make the text inside a GTK3 button object wrap around automatically.

So;

```
btn = gtk_button_new();
gtk_button_set_label (GTK_BUTTON(btn), "A very long label that should wrap");
```

**Does not wrap** - the button just extends to fit (unwanted behaviour here).

However:

```
label = gtk_button_get_label(GTK_BUTTON(dbp->btn));
if (GTK_IS_LABEL (label))
{
     g_message("Is label");
     gtk_label_set_ellipsize(GTK_LABEL(label),PANGO_ELLIPSIZE_END);
     gtk_label_set_line_wrap(GTK_LABEL(label), TRUE);
     gtk_label_set_max_width_chars(GTK_LABEL(label), 14);
}
```

This throws compile errors at the first line, which you might expect given that [gtk_button_get_label](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Button.get_label.html) returns a gchar string NOT an actual label widget.

```
warning: assignment to ‘GtkWidget *’ {aka ‘struct _GtkWidget *’} from incompatible pointer type ‘const gchar *’ {aka ‘const char *’} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    label = gtk_button_get_label(GTK_BUTTON(btn));
```

So, it looks like we can nicely wrap label widgets anywhere else but NOT button labels. Can anyone fill in the missing piece of the puzzle?

Comment: `GtkButton` is a container widget. Have you tried to use `gtk_bin_get_child` to get its label widget?

Comment: It can be even more complicated with nested containers. It would be better to recurse over child widgets and fing GtkLabel with GTK_TYPE_IS_LABEL macro

Answer (score 1):

It's python, but it's not difficult to translate it to C.
As I mentioned earlier, `GtkLabel` is a `GtkBin`, which creates some subwidgets: container, image, label. You have to recurse over it's children and find a label, only then you can set it's ellipsize parameter.

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf
from gi.repository import GObject as g
from gi.repository import Pango

def find_label(widget):
    # check if we've found a label
    #   there are convinient macros in C:
    #   is_label = GTK_IS_LABEL(widget) in this case
    if g.type_is_a(widget, Gtk.Label):
        return widget
    # if a container (or it's subclass)
    if g.type_is_a(widget, Gtk.Container):
        children = widget.get_children()
        for i in children:
            r = find_label(i)
            if r is not None:
                return r

def set_text_and_ellipsize(button, text):
    button.set_label(text)
    b = find_label(button)
    # In case we fail...
    if b is None:
        return
    # setting ellipsize
    b.set_ellipsize(Pango.EllipsizeMode.END)

# called on entry's text changed event
def text_changed(*args):
    text = entry.get_text()
    print(text)
    # initiates recreation of child GtkLabel widget
    set_text_and_ellipsize(button1, text)
    set_text_and_ellipsize(button2, text)
    set_text_and_ellipsize(button3, text)


win = Gtk.Window.new(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
grid = Gtk.Grid.new()
button1 = Gtk.Button.new()
button2 = Gtk.Button.new()
button3 = Gtk.Button.new()
entry = Gtk.Entry.new()
win.add(grid)
grid.add(button1)
grid.add(button2)
grid.add(button3)
grid.add(entry)
entry.connect("changed", text_changed)

win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - time pressures got the better of me and I re-implemented the whle sorry thing in HTML / browser in kiosk mode where I can at least better control the appearance so I can't (for now) say if this would work. Unfortunately the target is a working demo, no-one cares what's behind the curtain (yet).